# Sencha ExtJS to Microsoft Data Services for WCF: Easy way to append single quotes to the operation parameter?

Tags: extjs, wcf-data-services, url-parameters

I'm trying to use an combo item to query a WCF Data Service operation. Data Service wants the operation parameter enclosed in single quotes. Of course Sencha just stuffs the actual string into what is set as "queryParam". Is there an easy way (configure) to get it to quote the parameter, or am I going to have to code the building of the URI?

This sounds like such a stupid simple thing that I almost hate to ask. But, this represents a big disconnect between what WCF DS wants and what Ext produces and is going to cause pervasive problems with strings if I don't have the cleanest way to handle it in place.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something similar I wrote a custom proxy for the ext store.  The read function is where you have access to the operation's filters which you can turn into a filter string odata understands.  Then you have to make the request, format the response, and call the callback.

I don't know of an easier way.  There's an official-ish odata proxy for sencha touch [here](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/sencha-touch-odata-connector-for-sap) and one for extjs that was posted on the forums [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?194911-OData-proxy-for-ExtJS-4.1).  They might give you some ideas.